# How i can switch scene from a menubar or menuitem in javafx?

Tags: javafx

i have a real problem here, i have two scenes, in one scene i put a menu bar with menuitems, i want to create throw that menubar a link in the menuitem or  in menubar, I need a event or any function to create that link in the second scene. i apreciate any help

this is my code in the `start method`

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage ) throws IOException {

        //----------------------carga del primer contenedor-----------//
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane ();//parent
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Ventana.fxml"));
        AnchorPane root2 = new AnchorPane ();
        root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Enlace.fxml"));  
        //------------------------------------------------------------//
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();//declaracion del menu
        BorderPane ventana = new BorderPane();// declaracion del contenedor del menu //children
        ventana.setTop(menuBar);//colocar el menu en la parte de arriba del contenedor//
        Menu Agregar = new Menu("Archivo"); //creando la opcion del Menu archivo
        MenuItem PrimerItem= new MenuItem("Agregar Datos"); //creando el menu item 
        Agregar.getItems().addAll(PrimerItem);// agregando el item al menu
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(Agregar); //agregando el menu al menubar

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);// cargar la escena para que salga el contenedor principal
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2);
        root.getChildren().add(ventana); //carga el contenedor secundario dentro del principal

        primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);// preparar el contenedor de la escena y cargar la escena
        primaryStage.setTitle("prueba"); // colocarle el titulo
        primaryStage = (Stage) menuBar.getScene().getWindow();
        primaryStage.show();

    }
```

Comment: I think you just have to manually add the menuBar to all of the scenes that you want to use it in.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but if you are looking to reuse the same `MenuBar` in multiple scenes, you just need to make the MenuBar publicly available (either creating your own class that extends it or passing a reference to the menubar to all your scenes)